# Магический исходник на PHP7 (содержит одно слово head)

Tags: php

Создал файл `head.php`. В файле содержимое — одно слово — `head` (4 буквы без переноса строки).

Если открыть `http://url/head.php`, то будет показана пустая страница.
Если `head` заменить на `hea` или `heade`, то показывается нормально.

Баг/фича/яплохочиталхелп? Оно мне не мешает, просто случайно наткнулся и стало интересно. У вас так же?

Comment: `PHP 7.1.1`  Да нет,вроде все в порядке.

Comment: @whathef, а если в браузере просмотреть код страницы?

Comment: То есть в файле РНР просто букафы без `echo`, тегов и т.п.?

Comment: PHP 7.0.17 такое выдаёт

Comment: а если в браузере просмотреть код страницы? - чисто

Comment: То есть в файле РНР просто букафы без echo, тегов и т.п.? - так точно

Comment: Покажите лучше ваш `head.php`

Comment: Проверьте курлом/постманом, если все на месте - возможно, расширения браузера шалят. И да, на 7.0.19 всё ок.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BzwXTZ48

Comment: Расширений в браузере нет, но проверил и страница пустая.

Comment: никто не сможет воспроизвести....

Comment: Странно это всё )) На другом VPS с php 5.6 запустил та же песня )))

Comment: так может дело не в пэхапэ, а сэрвэрэ

Comment: две разных виртуалки. может в них дело. разбираться не буду.

Comment: а если файл переименовать в `tail.php` и вписать внутрь `tail` ?

Comment: @teran создал tail.php вписал "tail" не прокатило, показывает нормально. а вот если в 123.php переименовать то "head" всё-равно не видно. можно и дальше строку продолжить, например "head привет" тогда тоже ничего не покажет.

Comment: да, видимо в виртуалке дело. на дедике проделал тоже самое, всё отрабатывает как положено.